# app takes too long to launch and proceed from the splash/launch screen

Tags: react-native

I am developing a React Native Typescript Android and iOS mobile app, and my apps take too long to launch and proceed from the splash/launch screen. On my real Android device, it takes around 13 seconds to proceed from the splash/launch screen. On my real iOS device (iPhone 6s Plus), it takes around 23 seconds to proceed from the splash/launch screen. How can I avoid this? Online it says that it is due to the use of lots of packages but I need all the ones specified in `dependencies`. Some packages are required for the `react-navigation` to work. I have provided both my Android and iOS app's `package.json`. Both these projects are the same except for the versions of the packages.

Android

```json
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.8",
        "@react-navigation/elements": "1.3.18",
        "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.7",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.13",
        "axios": "1.4.0",
        "moment": "2.29.4",
        "react": "18.1.0",
        "react-native": "0.70.10",
        "react-native-animated-pagination-dot": "0.4.0",
        "react-native-dotenv": "3.4.9",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
        "react-native-keychain": "8.1.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
        "react-native-screens": "3.22.0",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
        "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
        "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
        "react-native-url-polyfill": "1.3.0",
        "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
        "react-native-youtube-iframe": "2.2.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.12.9",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "2.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
        "@types/react": "18.0.21",
        "@types/react-native": "0.70.6",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.37.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.37.0",
        "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "5.0.0",
        "eslint": "7.32.0",
        "jest": "26.6.3",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
        "typescript": "4.8.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ]
    }
}
```

IOS

```json
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.8",
        "@react-navigation/elements": "1.3.18",
        "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.7",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.13",
        "axios": "1.4.0",
        "moment": "2.29.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.1",
        "react-native-animated-pagination-dot": "0.4.0",
        "react-native-dotenv": "3.4.9",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
        "react-native-keychain": "8.1.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "3.3.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
        "react-native-screens": "3.22.0",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
        "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
        "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
        "react-native-url-polyfill": "1.3.0",
        "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
        "react-native-youtube-iframe": "2.2.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.8.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.22.5",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.20.0",
        "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.72.2",
        "@react-native/metro-config": "0.72.7",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "3.0.0",
        "@types/metro-config": "0.76.3",
        "@types/react": "18.0.24",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "29.2.1",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "5.0.0",
        "eslint": "8.19.0",
        "jest": "29.2.1",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
        "prettier": "2.4.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "4.8.4"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=16"
    }
}
```